# Unable to run assembly program. "Cannot find entry symbol _start"

Tags: assembly

I am currently trying to compile a basic program in assembly and get it to run. This is currently the code I have:

```
section .text
    global_start

_start:
    mov edx, len
    mov ecx, msg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

section .data
    msg db 'Hello world!', 0xa
    len equ $ - msg
```

I am using yasm to assemble the code. I do this by going into a Ubuntu terminal and typing:

```
yasm -f elf64 -o firstProgram.o firstProgram.asm
ld -d -o firstProgram firstProgram.o
./first
```

however before I can type in ./first I get this error:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000000040080.
```

(there may be a zero or two missing in that number above). Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: It's `global _start`; you're missing a space.

Comment: @fuz My god I am stupid. For some reason I didn't think the spaces were that important for whatever reason. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Considering I have recently seen somebody using `0x DB` .... They may be very very important, if you have some space missing or abundant in some unfortunate place. Most of the time abundant spaces are bigger problem, but you managed to find the case where missing one hurts... :)

Comment: @Ped7g Indeed, starting an identifier with undescore character is unfortunate place as well. Especially when some stupid linker puts there two or more adjacent undescores. 
I hate labels like **___start**, one never knows how many character they consist of, when printed.